# Changing colour of borderBottom on top location address

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a very basic menu for my site and I have used the border-bottom property to underline the items. What I want is to highlight the underline pink if you're on a certain page. I've used custom "url" elements and "link" attributes. I would like it so if the user is on page1 the page1 item would underline pink. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<script>
function col(){if(top.location.href==document.getElementsByTagName("url")[1].link){this.style.borderBottom="solid #F05";};}
</script>
```

^ That was completely wrong, I was testing with a bit of code from W3Schools.
I also tried:

```
<script>
function menuCol(url){if(top.location == url){this.style.borderBottom="solid #F05";};}
</script>
```

^ This one worked but I had to include "[PAGE NO]" on every page so the script could match the IDs of the page and URL element.

Does anyone know how I can actually make this work without having to put in pageID tags in?

----- Edit -----
Sorry, I'm not exactly sure how to put the problem into words but here's the page and source code (currently):

http://3659905.webs.com/ExternalPages/Desktop/Menubar_test.htm

```
<head>
<title>Menu</title>

<noframes></noframes><noscript></noscript><!-- --><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.freewebs.com/p.js"></script><script></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://images.freewebs.com/JS/Freebar/bar_sidegrey.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("url").click(function(){
top.location.href="http://"+$(this).attr("link")
});
});
</script>

<script>
function col(){if(top.location.href==document.getElementsByTagName("url")[1].link){this.style.borderBottom="solid #F05";};}
</script>

<style>
url{text-decoration:none;font-size:15px;padding:3px;border-bottom:solid #AAA;}
url:hover{cursor:pointer;border-bottom:solid #FFF}

body{background:black;color:white;font-family:arial;cursor:default;}
</style>
</head>



<body onselectstart="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;" onload="col();">
<center>

<url link="3s.uk.to">Home</url>
<url link="3apps.uk.to">App Store</url>
<url link="3659905.webs.com/ExternalPages/Desktop/Menubar_test.htm">Menu Test</url>

</center>
</body>
```

Comment: What mark-up are you using? What type of URL are you using (root-relative, relative or absolute)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand the problem even after reading it few times. Could you please provide complete code snippet? How is menuCol getting called? Could you use JQuery? You say this one worked but you did not use page number in code snippet provided. What do you mean by URL element?

Comment: TBH, I have no idea. Would it help if I said I'm using a Webs.com subdomain? List of URLs I want to use: http://3659905.webs.com/index.htm, http://3659905.webs.com/Apps/Store.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best guess I could make, given the sparsity of information in the question, is this:

```
// in real life, use:
// var url = window.location;
var url = "http://some.domain.com/index.html";

function markActive(elem) {
    if (url.indexOf(elem.href.split('/').pop()) > -1) {
        return 'active'
    }
}

var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0,len=as.length; i<len; i++){
    as[i].className = markActive(as[i]);
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aB3s5/1/).

This, in its current incarnation, works only for the name of the page, so if you had multiple `index.html` pages, albeit in different directories, they would all assign the active class (if you were currently in `www.example.com/index.html`).

Answer (score 0):

As they said, we need more code.

But if you want to take the current "pagename" and get the links containing that page you could do this:

```
//get current adress
var URL = window.location.pathname;
//get the filename with extension
var PageName = URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
//use jquery to find links pointing to the file
$('#YOURMENU a[href='+PageName+']').css("border-bottom-color", "#F05");
```